# How to set UIImageView as a title so that the stuff is not stretch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I do the following, then `titleView` will get stretched:

```
UIImage * img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"isikota_small.png"];
UIImageView * uiImage= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
self.navigationItem.titleView = uiImage;

PO(self.navigationItem.titleView);
```

If I do

```
UIImage * img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"isikota_small.png"];
UIImageView * uiImage= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
uiImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,66,33);

uiImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
//[self.navigationItem.titleView addAndResizeSubView:uiImage]; doesn't work


self.navigationItem.titleView = uiImage;
PO(self.navigationItem.titleView);
```

the title view will also get stretched.

If I do:

```
UIImage * img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"isikota_small.png"];
UIImageView * uiImage= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
uiImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,66,33);

uiImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
//[self.navigationItem.titleView addAndResizeSubView:uiImage]; doesn't work
UIView * uiv = [[UIView alloc]init];
[uiv addSubview:uiImage];
uiv.frame = CGRectMake(127, 0, 66, 33);
uiv.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

self.navigationItem.titleView = uiv;
PO(self.navigationItem.titleView);
```

Somehow Apple changes the `uiv.frame` to `CGRectMake(127, 6, 66, 33)`.

There has to be an elegant solution.

Comment: what is your image height & width ?

Comment: may be `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` can save you.

Comment: 66 * 33 That's the image width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use custom views as `titleView`, as well as for section footers and headers in tableViews and other similar use cases, iOS will ignore the offset part of your view's frame or change it in some not readily predictable way. To go around this issue you will need to create a container view such that your container has offsets (0,0):

Try something like this:

```
UIImage * img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"isikota_small.png"];
UIImageView * uiImage= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
uiImage.frame = CGRectMake(127,0,66,33);

UIView * uiv = [[UIView alloc]init];
[uiv addSubview:uiImage];
uiv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66+127, 33);

self.navigationItem.titleView = uiv;
```

I'm not sure if the autoresizing masks are throwing it off as well, so try it without any masks and see if you can get the behaviour you want.

Comment: I added a UIView for that. The thing is it mess things up. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am using something like this myself. I am not sure what your intention is in terms of resizing the image in the titleView, as I only used this to adjust positioning of the title, not its size. If you still have problems, try adding a screenshot to your question so that we can see what the problem is and what you want it to look like.